# Escape html with mvc3 razor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to create a link that just triggers a javascript function with parameters set by my mvc model. I have something that looks like this

```
<a onclick="$('foo_@Model.bar').toggle()"></a>
```

However this literally makes the onclick element 'foo@Model.bar' instead of printing the contents of Model.bar. How do I escape the Html without altering it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add brackets, tested it and works fine:

```
<a onclick="$('foo_@(Model.bar)').toggle()"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add parenthesis:

```
<a onclick="$('foo_@(Model.bar)').toggle()"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a onclick="$(@string.Format('foo_{0}',Model.bar)).toggle()"></a>
```