# Combining Code and Text in HTML Attribute with Razor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am creating a bunch of `<div>` elements using a `foreach` loop with Razor syntax. Right now I have this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="grid_6 listColumn" id="team_@item.TeamID">
    ...
    </div>
}
```

Basically I want the div identifiers to be labeled by the value in `item.TeamID` like:

team_1
team_2
team_3

The syntax I currently have doesn't recognize the code portion. I also tried `id="team_@:item.TeamID"` but it throws an error. However, `id="team_ @item.TeamID"` works fine, but I don't want that space in there. I'm pretty new to Razor, is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="grid_6 listColumn" id="@("team_" + item.TeamID)">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, that works. also, just came across [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373917/escape-html-with-mvc3-razor) which let me know `id="team_@(item.TeamID)"` works too.