# Why razor doesnt work in following example?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

```
<div class="jplayer" id="jplayer_@Model["id"]_@od["number"]"></div>
```

It doesn't insert value but writes exactly what you see. Variables exist because this code work perfectly:

```
<div class="music_player @Model["id"]"></div>
```

So what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<div class="jplayer" id="jplayer_@(Model["id"])_@(od["number"])"></div>
```

It sounds similar to my question: [Combining Code and Text in HTML Attribute with Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8936516/213159)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="music_player @(Model["id"])"></div>
```

And

```
<div class="jplayer" id="jplayer_@(Model["id"])_@(od["number"])"></div>
```

As per [Phil Haack's C# Razor Syntax Quick Reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx), you need to enclose your Razor expression in parenthesis with a prefix of the `@`.

Comment: these were already strings, but brackets work as in mhornfeck answer - thanks!

Comment: @Carlos Ok, I wasn't sure of that, but I took out the `ToString()` calls.